# Geosparql geof:distance measurement in query yields bad or no result

Tags: graphdb, geosparql

I am new to geosparql, I try to measure distances between location on earth. My training sample is a simple `turtle` file derived from a `graphDB` example. It contains two points only, one in Paris the other in Lyon referenced in `EPG:2154`. :

I compute the distance with the following request :

```
OGC/1.0/>
PREFIX qudt: <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?o1 ?o2 ?dist (geof:distance(?o1, ?o2, uom:metre) as ?dist) WHERE {
    ex:WMPoint geo:asWKT ?o1 .
    ex:APPoint geo:asWKT ?o2 .
    }
```

The answer is  *[ answer : "395913.0575631152"^^xsd:double] .* If I change the value of `(geof:distance(?o1, ?o2, uom:metre) as ?dist)`  I am stuck with the following situations :

- with `(geof:distance(?o1, ?o2, uom:meter) as ?dist)`   -> empty reply
- with `(geof:distance(?o1, ?o2) as ?dist)`   -> crazy reply *["4.017890202637487"^^xsd:double]*
- with `(geof:distance(?o1, ?o2, qudt:M) as ?dist)`      -> empty reply
- with `(geof:distance(?o1, ?o2, qudt:KiloM) as ?dist)`  -> empty reply

Is that a normal behavior ? Am I using `qudt` in a wrong way or `graphDB` is it not able to use `qudt` ?  I have also tried to compute distance in meters with (lon,lat) coordiantes in default CRS `CRS:84` but it failed and I get an empty answer or degree/crazy answer. Is there a way to obtain from `geosparql request` with (lon,lat) values an answer in kilometers ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- You can see in https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.5/geosparql-support.html#example-4
- That it uses units from http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/
  https://defs.opengis.net/vocprez/object?uri=http%3A//www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/
- This "redirects" to https://defs.opengis.net/vocprez/object?uri=http%3A//www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/
- Which shows there are only 5 units allowed:

```
degree
grid spacing
meter
metre
radian
unity
```

- So you cannot use qudt:M or qudt:KiloM. To convert to km, just divide by 1000
- I thought the crazy reply "4.017890202637487" is degrees latitude. But according to https://sciencing.com/convert-distances-degrees-meters-7858322.html, a degree latitude is 111,139 m, so your distance would be 3.56232285696 degrees. I'll post a bug
- Also, I'll post a doc bug: the units allowed with `geof:distance` should be documented at

  - https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.5/geosparql-support.html#example-4
  - https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.5/sparql-ext-functions-reference.html#geosparql-functions

Comment: internal ref: https://ontotext.atlassian.net/browse/GDB-9320

Comment: Thanks@Vladimir  for the answer. I came across the links and I used `uom:metre` or `uom:meter` to get the correct answer, which is OK and of course I can divide the result to get Km. My concern was about the use of `qudt` ontology which seems to be recommended by [OGC 1.1](https://opengeospatial.github.io/ogc-geosparql/geosparql11/spec.html#Recommendation%20for%20specification%20of%20units%20of%20measurement) which is not accepted `qudt:M` being equivalent to `uom:meter`. Am I using it in a wrong way or should I simply wait a new version of `GraphDB` accepting `qudt` to use it ?

Comment: I've had a long discussion with the GeoSPARQL community: https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogc-geosparql/issues/468. I'm now trying to understand which units are supported by GraphDB; but surely they'll be in the `uom` dataspace. I don't expect GraphDB to support QUDT units for this function.